# Stop ASP calendar refreshing page on every change (day,month...))

Tags: asp.net

ASP calendar is refreshing page on every change (day,month...) How can I stop that?

```
<asp:Calendar AutoPostback = "false" EnableViewState="true" SelectedDate="<%# DateTime.Now.Date %>" ID="Calendar1" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="White" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="9pt" ForeColor="Black" Height="190px" NextPrevFormat="FullMonth" Width="250px">    
    <DayHeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="8pt"></DayHeaderStyle><NextPrevStyle VerticalAlign="Bottom" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="#333333"></NextPrevStyle>
    <OtherMonthDayStyle ForeColor="#999999"></OtherMonthDayStyle>
    <SelectedDayStyle BackColor="#333399" ForeColor="White"></SelectedDayStyle
    <TitleStyle BackColor="White" BorderColor="Black" BorderWidth="0px" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="12pt" ForeColor="#333399"></TitleStyle>
    <TodayDayStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC"></TodayDayStyle>
</asp:Calendar>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this from your aspx page

```
SelectedDate="<%# DateTime.Now.Date %>"
```

... and put this in your Page_Load()

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        Calendar1.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
}
```